# How do I hide the Monad instance of [] (or [] in general)?

Tags: list, haskell, import, monads

I'm trying to work through some of the exercises in the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia), but I'm having trouble defining my own Monad instance of `[]`, because I can't seem to hide it. I was able to hide `Maybe` effectively, but when I try to hide `[]`, I get this error: `parse error on input '['`

I'm using this line of code to import:

```
import Prelude hiding (Maybe, Just, Nothing, [])
```

Changing `[]` to `([])` doesn't fix this issue, either.

I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try `-XNoImplicitPrelude`, but easiest is probably to define your own `List` type with semantics equivalent to `[]` and implement your instances for this type.

Hiding instances is not possible, as even `import Prelude ()` would import instances.

Comment: I feel like the exercise is kind of...too much, in that case. Implementing all of the convenience functions for `[]` is a hefty job. I was thinking that the monad instance of `[]` could be defined as `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs`. I'm just sort of wondering if that would work, but I can't check it without building up my own `List`, which is bizarre... Not your fault or anything, but I think it's silly for the page to provide such an exercise if it's not possible to implement directly.

Comment: Implementing the convenience functions for your own `List` type is easy if you first define your own `foldr`.  Assuming your constructors are called `Cons` and `Nil`: `map f = foldr (\x xs -> Cons (f x) xs) Nil`; `append xs ys = foldr Cons ys xs`; `concat = foldr append Nil`; `concatMap f = concat . map f`.

Comment: can't your own `List` type just be a `newtype` over `[]`?

Comment: @Benjamin Implementing concatMap itself could be a decent exercise.

Comment: @newacct Yes, you can do it that way, and then you could inherit whatever instances you want and use a Foldable/Traversable foldr, etc.

Comment: `NoImplicitPrelude` does not get rid of list syntax. It'll get rid of all the `Monad` instances, but it'll also get rid of `Monad` itself, and you can't get it back without getting the instances too...

Comment: @Ben Millwood What about defining the `Monad` typeclass itself?

Comment: I suppose that would work. But the fact remains that list syntax itself is impossible to be rid of.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially the list syntax is magic and built-in. When Haskell was created, lists were considered so universal and so useful that they deserved special square-bracket syntax to make them extra convenient to use. Hence you cannot define your own list type with the same syntax as the built-in `[a]`, and likewise you cannot hide the `[]` syntax any more than you can hide keywords like `if` or `where`. That doesn't stop you from defining your own list type, defining conversion functions to and from the inbuilt list type. As others have pointed out, defining list functions for yourself is both not very hard and quite educational.

Of course, you could also define your own `Monad` class with an identical signature, and then use that.

Comment: One of my least favourite Haskell design decisions. `List` is trivial to define, and yet they hard-wired it? *sigh*

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: I get what you mean, but the commas-separated syntax *is* useful. I don't mind giving lists some special treatment given that they are so fundamental.

Comment: It would be nice if they did it the way they do with numbers - by making a _class_ so that any user-defined type can use the literal list syntax. As for having constructors named `:` and `[]`, that's just weird. :-P

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: type classes introduce ambiguity, though. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that it's not entirely obvious what the best way forward is.

Comment: Using square-bracket syntax for your own list types is now possible via [`-XOverloadedLists` and the `IsList` class](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedLists)